# Dynamic loading using systemjs, how to not load all files at once?

Tags: javascript, typescript, systemjs

There is a main `app.js` file which has `import {Route} from "./router"`. Router - a class that depending on the the current `url` of page, will create an instance of this page handler. For example, for page `/home/accountPage` - router will create a handler in this way: `return new AccountPageHandler(params)`. It turns out that in the router imported all handlers of all pages (and them so much). And when I do `System.import ( 'js/app.js')` I will loaded all the scripts, including and unnecessary - because they are imported into the router, and the router imported in app.js.

How can I make so that does not import all at once, and only that I want to use? I am sure that this problem is already getting up earlier for many developers, but how to fix it - I have no idea because I faced with for this first time.

**P.S.**

My javascript is generated from the typescript (if suddenly this affects the options for solving the problem).

Comment: I am having the same issue. Looking forward to any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeng the actual code, my guess is SystemJS imports all of your scripts because you `import` all handlers of all pages. What you could do (if your router supports promises and async loading of page handlers). Is to use `System.import('specific_page_handler.js')` to import only the page handler needed right now.

But depending on the size of you app, and on the size of separate chunks you can lazy-load, just creating a minified bundle, setting a long cache expiration, and loading all at once can be just fine. Possibly small gains with added complexity.